# In a WatchService, what happens between key.pollEvents() and key.reset()?

Tags: java, events, watchservice

Looking at this [Java example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html), about the key state, Oracle says:

> **Ready** indicates that the key is ready to accept events. When first
>   created, a key is in the ready state.
>
> **Signaled** indicates that one or more events are queued. Once the key
>   has been signaled, it is no longer in the ready state until the reset
>    method is invoked.

In [`WatchKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html) javadoc:

> Events detected while the key is in the signaled state are queued but
>   do not cause the key to be re-queued for retrieval from the watch
>   service

The documentation doesn't say what happens to events generated between `key.pollEvents()` and `key.reset()`? **It is assumed that events will be buffered until the key is reset**, and the key will be signaled immediately after the reset. This seems supported by the test below.

**Could you point me to some *official* documentation? or to a discussion about the lack of documentation?**

---

```
Path dir = Paths.get("test");
WatchService watcher = dir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
dir.register(watcher, CREATE, DELETE, MODIFY);
while (true) {
    WatchKey key = watcher.take();
    System.out.println("polling.");
    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
        ... (details removed) ...
        System.out.format("  Event %s in [%s] for entry [%s]%n",
                          event.kind().name(), registeredDir, childPath);
        try { Thread.sleep(20000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { ; }
    }
    System.out.println("resetting.");
    key.reset();
}
```

... within the 20s allowed by the `sleep()`, I did:

- Create a file,
- Edit it, save it,
- Rename it,
- Edit it, save it,
- Delete it

Output:

```
polling.
  Event ENTRY_CREATE in [test] for entry [test\file1.txt]
resetting.
polling.
  Event ENTRY_MODIFY in [test] for entry [test\file1.txt]
  Event ENTRY_DELETE in [test] for entry [test\file1.txt]
  Event ENTRY_CREATE in [test] for entry [test\file2.txt]
  Event ENTRY_MODIFY in [test] for entry [test\file2.txt]
  Event ENTRY_DELETE in [test] for entry [test\file2.txt]
resetting.
```

---

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like additional events are buffered and will be processed or given the event type of OVERFLOW when the buffer fills up.

from the documentation for watchservice :

"File systems may report events faster than they can be retrieved or processed and an implementation may impose an unspecified limit on the number of events that it may accumulate. Where an implementation knowingly discards events then it arranges for the key's pollEvents method to return an element with an event type of OVERFLOW. This event can be used by the consumer as a trigger to re-examine the state of the object."

Comment: Do you have a reference to confirm this possibility?

Comment: @mins Im just looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html  I haven't tested it.

Comment: I edited my question to show some testing I have done, OVERFLOW is not triggered. It seems events are buffered and made available as soon as the key is reset. But I can't find any confirmation.

Comment: @mins this is one of the test suite examples to induce an OVERFLOW. https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk9u/blob/master/jdk/test/java/nio/file/WatchService/LotsOfEvents.java